# When I use ssh with putty my shell prompt is not the way I want it

Tags: command-line, bash, ssh

I have a `.bashrc` file that configures my shell prompt. 
When I connect to myself with ssh I have this prompt:

```
jebik@ns3000***:~$
```

When I `su` myself to another login or when I just launch `bash` I get this prompt:

```
jebik:/home/jebik$
```

This is the one I want, with username and path.

Why is my prompt not the right one when I first connect with PuTTY?

EDIT

When I login via putty i get this prompt:

```
jebik@ns3000***:~$
```

Which is from `/etc/bash.bashrc`

And the one I want is this one

```
jebik:/home/jebik$
```

From `/home/jebik/.bashrc`

Here is a list of first commands I do after a login

```
jebik@ns3000**:~$ echo $PS1
${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$
jebik@ns3000***:~$ cat /home/jebik/.bashrc
cd

alias ne='emacs'
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
alias ll='ls -lA'

PS1="\\e[0;31m\\u\e[m:\e[0;32m\\w\\e[m$ "
jebik@ns3000**:~$ bash
jebik:/home/jebik$ echo $PS1
\e[0;31m\u\e[m:\e[0;32m\w\e[m$
jebik:/home/jebik$
```

Comment: Please add a little more detail: What *exactly* did you do, what did you want to achieve and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warnings or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety by editing your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. [How do I ask a good question?](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Especially it's unclear which prompt you want, which one you get when you login via `ssh` and what you need to do to get your desired prompt. Btw, is this an issue with `ssh` in general or just `PuTTY`?

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/972616/edit) and add the content of your `~/.bashrc` file in a code block (`{}` button).

Comment: What is the output of `printf "%q\n" "$PS1"`

Comment: Your local prompt and remote machines' prompt can be different. Try to configure the remote machine with same prompt https://superuser.com/questions/221001/pushing-my-ps1-prompt-over-ssh

Comment: Could you please clarify which value of `PS1` originates from which login type? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

When you `su` you go into the prompt for the other user.

Your `.bashrc` file that is at `/home/jebik/.bashrc` will only apply settings to your profile.

There is another version of it for root at `/root/.bashrc`

There are global settings for all users in the file `/etc/bash.bashrc` as well.

There are some examples on this page on how to configure the prompt format to your liking. 
https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-bash-shell-setup-prompt.html

Comment: Ok apparently for some reason it get the PS1 from /etc/bash.bashrc the first time i login. any idea why?